# SR-IOV not working on Ubuntu 20.04 (hyper-v), works fine on 18.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, hyper-v, sr-iov, ubuntu-20.04

I'm running Ubuntu server virtual machines on a Windows Server 2019 system using Hyper-V.
The system is equipped with an Intel I350 network adapter. (The Ubuntu VM's recognize it as "Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I350 Virtual Function (rev 01)" )

The Ubuntu 18.04 machines are using SR-IOV out of the box.
These are using the kernel: 4.15.0-99-generic #100-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 22 20:32:56 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

When I upgraded these 18.04 machines to the latest HWE kernel, SR-IOV stopped working. 
Hyper-V reports the network adapters state to be degraded (SR-IOV not operational)
I submitted a bug on launchpad about this issue, over a year ago, but never received an answer (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-hwe/+bug/1818400)

With the new Ubuntu 20.04 release I'm having the same problem. SR-IOV is not working out of the box on these new Ubuntu VM either.

Does someone here know how to get SR-IOV working on newer kernels? Or how to raise this bug with the Ubuntu developers so that it gets their attention?

What I've already tried:
I've compared the kernel modules loaded between the 18.04 and 20.04 machines.
On the 20.04 machine I enabled all the missing modules from the 18.04, inside the /etc/modules file:

- ib_cm
- ib_core
- ib_iser
- iscsi_tcp
- iw_cm
- rdma_cm
- libiscsi
- libiscsi_tcp
- pcbc

I noticed these three modules could not be loaded on 20.04:

- pps_core
- ptp
- aes_x86_64